# Changing the header of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, format

I am trying to reformat my data frame in R. My current data frame in R looks like this:

```
V1 V2
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
5  0
```

However, I am wanting to reformat it so I looks like this:

```
variableStep chrom=1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried using colnames(df) <- 'variableStep chrom=1', however it returns this:

```
variableStep chrom=1   
1                      0
2                      0
3                      0
4                      0
5                      0
6                      0
```

Can anyone help? I just want 'variableStep chrom=1' as a header over both columns, not just one.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible, every column must have a name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
colnames(df) <- c("variableStep", "chrom=1")
```

The `c` concatenates the two strings to a vector of strings of length 2.

Comment: I just want it as one header over the data frame. Not two separate headers.

Comment: data.frames do not have a header, they are lists of vectors.

Comment: I am wanting to add a header line for wig format.

Comment: I am not familiar with that format but google finds packages for reading and writing this format from R as in https://rdrr.io/bioc/rtracklayer/man/WIGFile-class.html  These packages are likely the place to look for an answer